# Why I got null instead of Map object? How to fix this?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I'm writing an Android application and I encountered with a problem: I got a null instead of ImmutableMap object. It seems my Map is being garbage collected. But I created a reference to it. So here is all my source code with detail description of the problem in the comments:

```
//I have a BaseActivity class in which i defined nested class
//which incapsulates some REST operations
public class BaseActivity extends Activity
 {   
//Here is this ImmutableMap to which I want save the result
private ImmutableMap<String, Object> serverData_;

//Here is this nested class which is AsyncTask
class RestfulNetworkTasks extends AsyncTask
    <Pair<String,LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>, Void, LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>
{    
     NetworkOperation LowLevelRestOperations_ = new NetworkOperation(); 
    @Override
    protected LinkedHashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(Pair<String,LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>... params)    
   { 
    return  LowLevelRestOperations_.executeServerCommand
          (params[0].getValue0(), params[0].getValue1());
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(LinkedHashMap<String, Object> result)
    {  
        //Here i created a reference to the result(in order
        //to save it in my data structure)
        serverData_ = copyOf(result);
        UpdateCurrentActivityAfterNetworkOperation();
        //Here I made a test output to check if i got the result
        //All is good - I got a correct result saved to serverData_
        android.util.Log.d("TEST RESPONSE", "ON POST" + serverData_);
    }
}//End of nested class declaration
   //Here is my method in which i want to call AsyncTask and got a problem
   public void  Login(LinkedHashMap<String,Object> parameters)
   {   
//Here I create an instance of that nested AsyncTask class
RestfulNetworkTasks serverOperation_ = new RestfulNetworkTasks();
Pair<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> params_ = 
new Pair<String,LinkedHashMap<String,Object>>(LOGIN_COMMAND, parameters);
//Here I call AsyncTask operation - i got a correct ON POST output
     //with correct data
serverOperation_.execute(params_);

//But from this point my serverData_ is null!
//And I got null in AFTER POST output!Why?serverData_ is a member of BaseActivity so 
//it have to keep the result.
android.util.Log.d("TEST RESPONSE", "AFTER POST" + serverData_);
}
```

So how to fix this? Why my serverData_ is null after calling execute?

I really need a help - I'm really new to Java and Android and this problem made me crazy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code style would make an experienced Java programmer weep.  1) The indentation looks like a dogs breakfast.  2) Variable and method names should **always** start with a lowercase letter.  3) The underscore character should not be used in variable names.  4) If your indentation was correct you wouldn't comments like `//End of nested class declaration`

Comment: @StephenC Thanks for the comments. I'm still learning. And i said about this: "I'm really new to Java...". So for an experienced java programmer I look like a kid may be.

Comment: ImmutableMap is a com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap?

Comment: @pomkine Yes. It's from Google Guava

Comment: @HarryCater So you should try to init Map like this: ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Object> paramsMap = ImmutableMap.builder(); paramsMap
                .put(...).build()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my serverData_ is null after calling execute?

because *AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread*  without making wait on UI Thread (like Thread) until Thread execution is not completed.

if you want to Wait on main ui thread until AsyncTasks computation is not complete and get result back then use [AsyncTask.get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) .

Example:

```
serverOperation_.execute(params_).get();  //<<<< 

// now u get latest value in serverData_
android.util.Log.d("TEST RESPONSE", "AFTER POST" + serverData_);
```

Comment: Ok. Is it the only way to save the result with my current implementation design? And won't this "if you want to Wait on main ui thread until AsyncTasks computation is not complete" cause a performance overhead?

Comment: @HarryCater : 
yes if u use  AsyncTask.get()  for getting result back from AsyncTask this will freeze current UI until AsyncTask computation is not  complete (or control not return until back to Main UI Thread). instead of using AsyncTask.get() use onPostExecute method

Answer (score 1):

> It seems my Map is being garbage collected.

No that is not the problem.  Objects that you could possibly use will not be garbage collected.  Not ever.

The real problem is that the variable wasn't assigned a value before you used it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems object serverData_ is not initialized yet, in you code you have called serverData_ = copyOf(result); statement in thread, that may executed in future, before that you are using serverData_ that will be null until onPostExecute finishes. Please wait until your AsyncTask completes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the ImmutableMap.  If this is the google version, once created it cannot change.  One solution would be to use the regular java library functions to allocate and build up your Map, then use the Collections interface to return and unmodifiable view; something like:

```
HashMap<String, Object> modifiableMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();   
modifiableMap.put("1", new Object());   
modifiableMap.put("2", new Object());   
Map<String, Object> unmodifiableMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(modifiableMap);
```

Alternatively, you can stick with the google implementation, but you need to use their builder methods; something like:

```
ImmutableMap<String, Object> map = ImmutableMap.builder()
    .put(key, value);
    .build();
```